# nginx.conf server_name behaviour

Tags: docker, nginx

I am using Nginx Docker official image. I am overriding `nginx.conf` through `Dockerfile`and I am not including the default configuration. Inside the new **nginx.conf** I have the following server context:

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    index index.html;
    server_name localhost1;
    listen 80;
}
```

I am running the container by

```
docker run -d -p  3000:80 <image-name>
```

Then, putting http://localhost:3000 in the browser
does work.
However, what I shoud expect is 'server_name' value (**localhost1**) to match '**localhost**' specified in the browser and since there is no match, failure could make sense. So, why '**localhost1**' does not create any issues?

Comment: Read [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) documentation chapter, what _default server_ exactly is.

Comment: The wording of the question is a little idd but you are describing the implicit default server behavior of nginx.